# Using embedded columns

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the TensorFlow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) on wide and deep learning. The demo application creates indicator columns for categorical features with few categories (gender, education), and it creates embedded columns for categorical features with many categories (native_country, occupation).

I don't understand embedded columns. Is there a rule that clarifies when to use embedded columns instead of indicator columns? According to the documentation, the `dimension` parameter sets the dimension of the embedding. What does that mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808643/tf-contrib-layers-embedding-column-from-tensor-flow

Answer (score 1):

From [the feature columns tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/feature_columns#indicator_and_embedding_columns):

> Now, suppose instead of having just three possible classes, we have a million. Or maybe a billion. For a number of reasons, **as the number of categories grow large, it becomes infeasible to train a neural network using indicator columns**.
>
> We can use an embedding column to overcome this limitation. **Instead of representing the data as a one-hot vector of many dimensions, an embedding column represents that data as a lower-dimensional, ordinary vector in which each cell can contain any number, not just 0 or 1.** By permitting a richer palette of numbers for every cell, an embedding column contains far fewer cells than an indicator column.

The `dimension` parameter is the length of the vector you're reducing the categories to.